# environment variables type casting

Tags: php, symfony, environment-variables

I am finding myself in the situation where I need to deal with some environment variables that are passed to some type-hinted classes methods and constructors that are complaining because they expect, say, an integer but they receive a string, as env vars are always strings, no matter their content.

I would like to keep strict type-hinting wherever possible, but the current solutions (such as Symfony DotEnv) don't seem to even consider the possibility of doing any type-casting.

How would you go about solving this problem? As I said, I'd like to avoid relaxing the class type-hinting, but the current status of env vars handling doesn't seem to suggest anything but strings are "correct".

Answer (score 0):

I'd be inclined towards using some form of proxy class that understands that it will get a string, but must provide the outputs as integers, and the like.

If there are a number of environment variables that go into the construction of the class(es) putting them in via some form of value-object (which would also convert them to a proper type), could also simplify the parameter list, and make it a little more obvious as to what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

After some tinkering and research, a colleague and I came up with a solution based on a parameter.php file(as opposed to parameters.yml), where we would get and type-cast the variables in-place as follows:

`$container->setParameter('foo.bar', (int) getenv('FOO_BAR'));`

It turned out the same need arose within the Symfony team as well: they solved the issue by allowing type-casting in DIC's Yaml files as presented in the following article > https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-4-advanced-environment-variables